# Enabling unity builds in meson causes vulkan-memory-allocator not to link

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compilation, vulkan, meson-build

Meson allows one to compile code with unity builds, one simply has to run the command:

`meson --reconfigure -Dunity=on`

To enable them.

I have a project that compiles and builds fine when they are off, if I enable them (and check with meson configure they are enabled)

I get linking errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: libCoreNeverEngine.so.p/meson-generated_CoreNeverEngine-unity10.cpp.o: in function `VulkanMemory::CreateBuffer(unsigned long, vk::Flags<vk::BufferUsageFlagBits>, vk::Flags<vk::MemoryPropertyFlagBits>)':
/home/makogan/neverengine_personal/build/../Src/Engine/Renderer/Rendering/VulkanLayer/Memory.cpp:154: undefined reference to `vmaCreateBuffer'
/usr/bin/ld: libCoreNeverEngine.so.p/meson-generated_CoreNeverEngine-unity10.cpp.o: in function `VulkanMemory::GetMemoryAllocationInfo(vk::Buffer)':
```

I would expect unity builds to cause name clashes, but I am not sure how this can produce linking errors.

Comment: Do you have a header that requires defines to get specific functions enabled? unity builds can cause those kind of bugs.

Comment: I do not, but my dependencies might.